# Error in my Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigationbar

I'm new to android, I have designed a navigation drawer and I want to show a message (as Toast) as every item is clicked, It runs but the message is not shown, can anyone help me please?

this is my code for showing the message:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    //}


    int MyID = item.getItemId();
    if (MyID == R.id.nav_account){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (MyID == R.id.nav_settings){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (MyID == R.id.nav_logout){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Log Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: provide us your full code.

Comment: You have given the code for the options menu selection, not for the navigation drawer. Please provide the full code

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the following method instead.

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.yourId:
                ...
                break;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `onOptionsItemSelected()`  is overridden when using options menu like this [Screenshot options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD9On.png)

But if you want to manipulate the select event of Navigation drawer you have to override `onNavigationItemSelected()` method.